# How to reconnect socket to the server if the socket wasn't disconnected/closed by the server?

Tags: c#

I have an TCP asynchronous project and there's a problem when it comes to reconnect the client to the server if the connection was closed.(wasn't closed by the server).

When the server is closed the client gets the following error :

```
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host at EndReceive(IAyncResult ar) at ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
```

PS:The client can only receive streams from the server.

Things being said , I understand that I need somehow to reconnect to the server .
I have tried to do something but it didn't worked because the client was not responding and exiting.

What I did was , in the catch block of the Receiving callback which contains the steps below , I set the ClientSocket to Disconnected(true) and in a while loop (!ClientSocket.Connected) , I was recalling the main method which starts the asynchronous operation again and the last line of code was Thread.Sleep(n);

These things are done in the receive callback

1. Getting the string from the buffer
2. Doing whatever.. with the string
3. Calling again BeginReceive

PS: I don't want to use another port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must catch that exception (you can look for specific error code) and then close that socket and get rid of it. Then create a new one from scratch.